# Can I declare a function using a type

Tags: delphi

I have a program which can use any combination of five DLLs to do some work. All the DLLs have the same interface, same exported functions and procedures, and only differ in what they actually do.

In order to make things easier, sanity-check-wise, I'd like to define the functions only once and then share the definition unit between anything. The problem then would be to define a function of a given type.

Imagine:

```
type
  TMyFunc = function(inP : Integer): outP : Boolean;
```

Can I now define a function called, say, `doit`, and force its definition to be of type `TMyFunc`, without redefining everything?

I can't just type:

```
function doit: TMyFunc;
```

Is there any way to do this?

It would really make defining everything easier, more secure and so on.

Right now, everything is defined several times, and making a necessary interface change at one point means that I need to remember to go everywhere and duplicate the change (and duplication is bad). If I could do the declaration in one place only then if I forgot to make a change somewhere compilation would fail, which would be great.

Comment: Why not create a common unit which is shared between each project? I have a couple projects where I have many DLLs sharing the same definitions, where I only define them once. There's no need to re-write everything for each DLL. I think you're looking for the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: That doesn't actually help when I'm declaring the functions in the DLLs, I have to manually ensure they respect the interface, or caller functions will break.  It's a shame I can't centralize this

Comment: Perhaps I just don't have enough information about what exactly you're doing. But there's surely a better solution. Of course the `implementation` of each DLL would be different, but the `interface` should likely be the same.

Comment: Here's an example.  I have this exact function declared in three DLLs.  I wanted a way to declare the function description as a type, and then reference this type as the actual function declaration, hence ensuring the interface is identical over the three DLLs, just in case i need to change something at some point, and forget to change it in three different places.  `FUNCTION getFile(jobName: STRING; fileName: STRING; engineParams: TStringList;
  fileContent: TStream; isCatalogueFile: Boolean = false): STRING;`

Comment: OK it's not ideal, but I can put in the DLL main code block (so initialization) : `var toto: TMyFunc;begin  toto := SomeFunc`    If `SomeFunc` is not of type `TMyFunc` I get a compiler error of 'Parameter Lists Differ'

Comment: What about an pascal include file containing he declaration of the functions or procedures. You can include this in the interface section of the main unit in each library.

Comment: But in the library you don't declare an interface, you just declare your functions & procedures and then export them.  And exports don't include parameter lists - it's up to the caller to pass the correct parameters

Comment: Take a look at one of my projects where I did something similar - although incomplete and not fully functional, the layout of the code should demonstrate what I'm talking about. Specifically the units in the `Services` directory: https://github.com/djjd47130/Weather

Comment: What is preventing you from using a unit to declare and define the exported functions. In the interface section of the unit add the inlcude file. Add this unit to your library. You can put the `exports`-clause in the include file, in the unit or in the library-project-file.

Comment: As an OO solution: I would suggest defining an abstract class with virtual abstract class functions. Then, for each DLL create a specific class which "fills in the meat" by calling the actyual function in the DLL. Like this, you can pass the class type to any caller, which allows the caller to call the "right" function without havind direct access to the DLL involved. So AAMOF wrap the DLL interface into a class. Using class functions allows you to call the functions without actually instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

The answer is, quite simply, no you cannot do this. When you declare a function, you must include its complete argument list, return type, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured...I kept hoping though :)

Answer (score 0):

THIS is wrong:

```
type
  TMyFunc = function(inP : Integer): outP : Boolean;
```

a function cannot have two return types (both outP and Boolean) !

INSTEAD:

```
type
    outP = Longint; // or whatever you want outP to be.

    TMyFunc1 = function (inP : Integer): outP;
    TMyFunc2 = function (inP : Integer): Boolean;
```

you can now define a function variable called, say, doit1, and force it's definition to be of type TMyFunc1. likewise: doit2 is type TMyFunc2.

```
var
    doit1 : TMyFunc1;
    doit2 : TMyFunc2;
```

if you have functions:

```
const
    DllName1 = 'MyFirstDLL.DLL';
    DllName2 = 'MySecondDLL.DLL';

function TestFunc1(inP : Integer): outP; external DllName1;

function TestFunc2(inP : Integer): Boolean; external DllName2;
```

then you can assign these functions to the placeholders doit1, doit2:

```
procedure AssignPlaceholders;
begin
    doit1 := TestFunc1;
    doit2 := TestFunc2;
end;
```

NOTE: You must declare the placeholder types (TMyFunc1, TMyFunc2) EXACTLY the same as the real functions, including specifiers such as stdcall, cdecl etc.

After you call AssignPlaceholders, you can call doit1 and/or doit2 just the same as any other function.